# How to create bar charts with multiple bar labels in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm trying to create a bar chart in which the frequency is outside the bar and the percentage inside, is it possible? Would post a picture but the system doesn't allow for it yet.

Comment: How about posting your code?

Comment: Please see the _Asking_ section in http://stackoverflow.com/help, to read on what constitutes a good question.

Comment: Sorry, as a STATA newbie this was the first Q&A site I found so didn't realize this was for STATA professionals only. Is there a similar place for STATA idiots like me somewhere? This is a sincere question, not a snarky reply, I'd like to learn more.

Comment: The points raised by others do not bear on whether you are a "professional", whatever that means. They just mean that on SO you should have some code and that you should show that code to us. But if you want to ask questions without code you are going to be a bit better off on www.statalist.org. It's true on any forum, however, that you are expected to consult documentation first. The spelling is "Stata", by the way.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, this is a poor question without code.

It is possible to guess that you are using `graph bar`. That makes you choose at most one kind and position of bar labels. Much more is possible with `twoway bar` so long as you do a little work.

```
sysuse auto, clear
contract rep78 if rep78 < .
su _freq
gen _pc = 100 * _freq / r(sum)
gen s_pc  = string(_pc, "%2.1f") + "%"
gen one = 1

twoway bar _freq rep78, barw(0.9) xla(1/5, notick) bfcolor(none) ///
|| scatter one _freq rep78, ms(none ..) mla(s_pc _freq) mlabcolor(black ..) ///
mlabpos(0 12) scheme(s1color) ysc(r(0 32)) yla(, ang(h)) legend(off)
```

[image]

In short:

1. `contract` collapses to a dataset of frequencies.
2. Calculation of percents is trivial, but you need a formatted version in a string variable if the labels are not to look silly. Precise format is at choice.
3. The frequency scale on the axis is arguably redundant given the bar labels, and could be omitted.
4. The example puts labels within the bar just above its base at the level of  frequency equal to 1. That's a choice for this example and would be too close to the axis if the typical frequencies were much higher.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. It's actually a catplot (not sure if the best choice,  but found it to work best with the very limited skills I've got) but apparently most of the bar options etc. are available for it.

Comment: Be careful what you say about `catplot`. I wrote it. However, it won't help you here as it is just a wrapper for `graph bar` etc.

Comment: catplot foreign, asyvars scheme(vg_blue) intensity(*.6) graphregion(color(*.5)) legend(rows(1) position (bottom) span) ylabel(, labsize(medsmall)) ymtick(50(100)350)  ytitle("") bar(5, color(*.7)) blabel(bar, pos(outside) gap(1)) l1title("") ysize(2.5) xsize(3.26)